# How can i create a Window where i can Ask "Are you sure, that you want to delete this Item."

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-webassembly, delete-row

I have a Razor Page where I display some accounts. I try to make a submit window if the administrator tries to delete a user. What I tried is to make an extra method to display the window. But I don't know how I should make a display, which gets created if an admin tries to delete an Item.

**HTML Part**

```
@foreach (var user in users)
{
                                <tr>
                                        <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                                        <td>@user.LastName</td>
                                        <td>@user.Email</td>
                                        <td>@user.UserName</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="(() => DeleteUser(user.Id))">✘</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
```

**C# Method**

```
    private async Task DeleteUser(string id)
        {
            responseMessages.Clear();
            var response = await Http.DeleteAsync($"{ServiceEndpoint}/User/{id}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
            {
                success = true;
                await GetAdminForeignKeys();
            }
            else
            {
                success = false;
                string responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                int startIndex;
                int endIndex;
                startIndex = responseMessage.IndexOf("\"errors\":");
                responseMessage = responseMessage.Substring(startIndex, responseMessage.Length - startIndex);
                while (responseMessage.IndexOf("[") != -1)
                {
                    startIndex = responseMessage.IndexOf("[") + 2;
                    responseMessage = responseMessage.Substring(startIndex, responseMessage.Length - startIndex);
                    endIndex = responseMessage.IndexOf("]") - 1;
                    responseMessages.Add(responseMessage.Substring(0, endIndex));
                }
            }
        }
```

[Something like this should be visible before the User gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEUeS.png)

I don't want to make an extra page and do it with an IFrame. So does anyone have an Idea how I can do this? I want as less code as I can. By the way, it's Dotnet Framework Core, Version 5.0.11. Thx for the help! :=)

[My Frontend right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ3U6.png)

Comment: Fixed the Codeimages and Copy + Pasted the real Code! Thx for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have three options

1. Create a javascript function and use  `confirm` javascript function inside it and [invoke it from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet)
   and then invoke a callback function with result from javascrript to C#
2. Create a Html modal ( [somthing like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) that developed by bootstrap)
3. Use Existing blazor third-party components like [blazorise](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/modal)

Comment: Yes thats what I need